# Querying Microsoft SQL SERVER 2008 from Linux

Tags: linux, windows

Basically I want to write all the lines of a text file present in linux machine to Microsoft SQL server database. I need a shell script to connect from my Linux machine to a remote Microsoft SQL Server (2008) database and do insertion. How do I do this?

Comment: That's nice to know, but what's the question?

Comment: @Macro : Basically I am not getting any way to connect to sql server database from Linux.Need help for that

Comment: What exactly do you want to do from the UNIX host with the SQL Server?  Just running SQL commands and seeing the output or writing a whole application/software? Or monitoring it in some way?

Comment: -1: It is completely unclear what you want. You want to connect to the SQL server installed on your machine, from the Unix machine that you logged in to? Or the other way around. Please be really specific, because I don't understand yet.

Comment: @Tonin : basically i want to write all the lines of a text file present in linux machine to SQL server database.Need a shell script to connect from my linux machine to a remote sql server database and do insertion.

Comment: @satyajit Can you maybe expend your question with the thing you wrote in the comments? Make sure there is no ambiguity left, so people understand what you want by only reading the question.

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28160 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa937724.aspx ... one or both of those should help. You'll have to write a minimal amount of code (well, actually, maybe not, since you can find things that already use ODBC or JDBC)

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, MSSQL Server is a modified version of a SyBase RDBMS.

At least with MSSQL 2005, the SyBase tools worked for MSSQL as well. It may still be the case with MSSQL 2008.

Look for FreeTDS, a free implementation for accessing such servers.

It comes with `sqsh`, a command-line SQL client, and also an ODBC driver which you can then use with any ODBC aware utility or language module (like perl's DBI).

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, you want to import the contents of a text file on a Unix or Linux OS in a SQL Server database. The first thing that comes to mind is that Unix/Linux and Windows use different characters for newlines, so a utility like dos2unix might be useful. Second, why not just use scp to copy the file to the SQL Server machine and import? Third, you're asking for trouble IMHO.

Comment: well microsoft DB is build to run with applicative so it doesn't really care from where you are connecting. As long as you have a driver for that. in this case I almost sure SQL server use ODBC and I can prove it --> http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28160